# the alert (X) close is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, alert

I've created an applicationfor an alert as documented in http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/alert_boxes.html , the alert box is comming but not able to close the alert box .

can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2vqSr/1/)**

```
<script>
$(document).foundation();
</script>
<br>
<br>
<div data-alert class="alert-box">
   MY CONTENT 
   <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: somehow it seems its not loading the foundation.js file, see the console for error log

Comment: If you look into your console you will see an javascript error: Timestamp: 5/20/2014 2:15:24 PM
Error: SyntaxError: syntax error
Source File: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/normalize.scss
Line: 6
Source Code:
<!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: you tagged it with javascript and jquery, so why not use script to handle the click event of the `.close` and close the alert accordingly? For a pure CSS solution, I don't think we have any ***clean*** solution while we can just have some job with `:focus` or `:target` but those are also triggered in another way than clicking (such as using tab).

Comment: but why that close is not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not adding correct resource files. All the css / js are linking to github pages for those files instead of actual css / js files.

Also, you are not initializing `foudation` js framework.

You need to add below code to initialize foundation js.

`$(document).foundation();`

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LxEYq/)

Answer (score 3):

In your jsfiddle you have included three resources. These are github display pages for the corresponding files. They are HTML and won't work. You need to include the raw files from a proper place, e.g. a CDN.

They seem to have their own CDN at http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.js which you can find in the Codepen example of their getting-started page.

BTW: I found this issue by using the javascript console which every major browser provides. More specifically I used Google Chrome's developer tools window. You can do the same to further narrow down your errors.

Comment: but why that close is not working, can you give me a solution

Comment: @Manu he already said in the answer, maybe you should have asked for some **updated demo** to show that it works now.

Comment: @Manu The "Getting started" section has a codepen example. From that I gather this link: http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.js

Comment: @Manu you need to fetch them from a CDN. Github delivers them with the wrong MIME type: `Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zurb/foundation/master/js/foundation/foundation.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

Comment: @chiccodoro can you show me one updated demo with that